# RDP sound from machine without soundcard

Tags: sound, remote-desktop, soundcard

Would it be possible to get a sound playback via RDP from machine with Ubuntu 22.04 with no physical soundcard?

When playing sound via RDP (connected with Reminna) I see on remote machine in Volume Control in the Output devices tab there is showing a "Dummy output", where the volume bar is moving as the audio is playing. Can I connect that somehow to RDP?

I tried to change Reminna settings, advanced tab, Audio output mode = Local, though, audio is not transmitted.

Would maybe some "virtual audio cable" help?